# Overplotting dynamically

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I need to plot a lot of lines, and I'd like to show them as they're calculated. The code looks something like this:

```
x = arange(100000)
for y in range(100000):
    ax.plot(x*y)
    draw()
```

Now, as you can imagine, this gets slow very quickly. What I was thinking I could do, is plot, save the plot to a buffer, clear the plot, lay down the buffer as a background and then plot the next line. This way, I don't end up with so many Line2D objects. Would anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you need matplotlib.animation feature. [animation examples](http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/examples/animation/index.html).

> EDIT: Added simpler example code of my own version.

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def data_generator(t):
    if t<100:
        return random.sample(range(100), 20)

def init():
    return plt.plot()

def animate(i):
    data = data_generator(i)
    return plt.plot(data, c='k')

fig = plt.figure()
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1000, interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

> EDIT2: Multiple line live update version.

```
import random
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
from matplotlib import animation

def data_generator_1(t):
    if t<100:
        x1.append(t)
        y1.append(random.randint(1, 100))

def data_generator_2(t):
    if t<100:
        x2.append(t)
        y2.append(random.randint(1, 100))

def init():
    global x1
    global y1
    x1 = []
    y1 = []

    global x2
    global y2
    x2 = []
    y2 = []

    l1, l2 = plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    return l1, l2

def animate(i):
    data_generator_1(i)
    data_generator_2(i)
    l1, l2 = plt.plot(x1, y1, x2, y2)
    plt.setp(l1, ls='--', c='k')
    plt.setp(l2, c='gray')
    return l1, l2

fig = plt.figure()
anim = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, init_func=init, frames=1000, interval=1000, blit=True)
plt.show()
```

[image]

I'm pretty sure that there is many ways of plotting this kind of animation without global variables. This is just fast trial to show you the possibilities of what you want.

I don't know about ipython/vanilla scripting issue which is regarded by your first comment. All examples are coded on normal editor(not ipython). Maybe there is matplotlib version difference.

Comment: What's odd is that this runs exactly as I want it to in an ipython notebook, but not from a script file run from the command line. Unfortunately, I need the latter.

Comment: I'm also receiving two data products from the data generator that need to be plotted. I could probably figure that out on my own, but if you have any insight, I would greatly appreciate it!

Comment: A clarification on my first comment: The first line plotted sticks on the graph, but every subsequent plot gets cleared before the following one gets plotted.

Comment: Thanks a bunch. It turns out if I set blit=False, everything seems to work.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, if you're using an ipython notebook, you can use the IPython display feature:

```
from IPython import display
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import numpy as np
%matplotlib

x = np.arange(100)

for y in np.arange(100):  
    fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,6))
    ax.plot(x * y)
    ax.set_ylim(0, 10000) # to keep the axes always the same
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(fig)
    plt.close()
```

If you want to have at any time say, 10 lines drew one at a time, you can do:

```
x = np.arange(100)
fig, ax = plt.subplots(1,1, figsize=(6,6))
for y in np.arange(100):        
    ax.plot(x*y)
    ax.set_ylim(0,10000)
    display.clear_output(wait=True)
    display.display(fig)
    if y > 10:           # from the 10th iteration,
        ax.lines.pop(0)  # remove the first line, then the 2nd, etc.. 
                         # but it will always be in position `0`
plt.close()
```

HTH